# What does "stagger" mean in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch, terminology

I frequently hear Overwatch players and commentators using the verb "stagger". What does this term refer to, and what is its significance?

Comment: (Despite the title, this is _not_ a dupe of the related question titled "What does 'stagger' mean?" -- that question is specific to Skyrim.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Staggering refers to respawn timers. If all enemy players die at about the same time, they will respawn and be regrouped at about the same time. But if you let a baby d.va live for a few extra seconds, that delays their next push by that much

Comment: It's interesting to note that Overwatch didn't implement Team Fortress 2's spawning system which is intentionally designed to spawn players together by varying spawns by up to 5 seconds.  i.e. if you spawn 3-4 seconds after another player, you're likely to be spawned together.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense in a more competitive game such as Overwatch, where literally a single second can be the difference between extending Overtime or not. "Not" arbitrarily adjusting timers keeps things "fair" as there is no rounding up or down which "might" benefit or hurt teams "depending". Instead it just "is what it is".